# Flutter - Notificacion push personalizada con una imagen de la app

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

Quiero mostrar el icono de la app en una notificacion push. Ya tengo todas las configuraciones y las notificaciones push estan funcionando. Pero necesito colocar el icono de la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso la libreria de firebase en el archivo pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_messaging: ^6.0.1
```

He buscado en google pero no encuentro alguna guia en Flutter,

Gracias de antemano

EDIT.

parte de mi codigo que recibe la notificacion push

```
FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging(); // variable global
...

class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseApp app;


  Start({Key key, this.app}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _InicioState createState() => _InicioState();
}

class _StartState extends State<Start> {

  DatabaseReference _messagesRef;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {},
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {},
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {},
    );
    _fcm.subscribeToTopic('notificaciones');
    getToken();
   }
  ...
 }
```

Comment: hmm como envías la notificación? que datos le envías?

Comment: gracias por responder @diegoveloper, en realidad no se muy bien como funciona, solo recibe el texto de la notificacion, voy a agregar mas codigo

Comment: ojo que una cosa es el icono de la app que aparece en la izquierda y otra es la imagen que muestras en la notificación que aparece en la derecha, por eso queremos saber como envías la notificación push ya que esta encarga de proveer la imagen

Comment: las notificaciones push son enviadas desde un codigo php en mi server, aqui solo envio el mensaje.

Comment: Pero, ¿es posible personalizar con una imagen (icono app) cuando se recibe en la aplicacion? la imagen marcada en verde quisiera que se muestre el icono de mi app

Comment: revisa esto para que le puedas enviar la imagen  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109597/discussion-between-wilmer-and-diegoveloper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para recibir imágenes en la notificación , tienes que enviarlo desde el server dentro del campo `notification`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image

```
{
  "message":{
    "token" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "android": {
       "notification": {
           "body" : "This is an FCM notification that displays an image.!",
           "title" : "FCM Notification",
           "image": "url-to-image"
       }
   }
}
```

Ojo que estas notificaciones solo las verás cuando la app está en background, si deseas mostrar una notificación cuando la app está en foreground,  tienes que adicionar este plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications , donde puedes guiarte de este ejemplo : https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/lib/main.dart